# issue while including another playbook in ansible?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

I have written a playbook named as `master.yaml` as defined below

```
- hosts: master
  remote_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Get env
      command: id -g -n {{  lookup('env', '$USER') }}
      register: group_user
      vars:
        is_done: "false"

    - include: slave.yaml
      vars:
        sethostname: "{{ group_user }}"
        worker: worker
      when: is_done == "true"
      where: inventory_hostname in groups['worker']
```

I am trying run another playbook named as `slave.yaml` as defined below, after a certain condition is met.

```
- hosts: worker
  remote_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Write to a file for deamon setup
      copy:
        content: "{{ sethostname }}"
        dest: "/home/ubuntu/test.text"
```

Now i have two question:

- I am not able to set the value of var `isDone`. slave.yaml should
  only work when `isDone` is true.
- 2.How salve.yaml access the value worker. I have defined group worker in inventory.yaml

Comment: Where and how do you want to get `is_Done` updated? Also your 2nd point is a bit unclear, can you add an example

Comment: I want to define is_Done at a global level and update it's value when Get env task is completed. slave.yaml will be executed on different VM so I want slave.yaml to access a worker from inventory file. This inventory file is same for master.yaml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if it's the right way to go to reach your objective. However I tried to make this playbook work by keeping as much as possible your logic. Hope it helps.

The point is that you cannot use `import_playbook` inside the play. Check the [module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html) for more information.
So I propose to share code with a **role** instead of a playbook. You will be able to share the `slave` role between the `master` playbook and another playbooks, a `slave` playbook for example.

The ansible folder structure is the following.

```
├── hosts
├── master.yml
└── roles
    └── slave
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

### Master.yml

```
---
- name: 'Master Playbook'
  # Using the serial keyword to run the playbook for each host one by one
  hosts: master
  serial: 1
  remote_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"

  tasks:
    - name: 'Get env'
      command: id -g -n {{ lookup('env', '$USER') }}
      register: group_user

    - name: 'Calling the slave role'
      import_role:
        name: 'slave'
      # The return value of the command is stored in stdout
      vars:
        sethostname: "{{ group_user.stdout }}"
      # Only run when the task get env has been done (state changed)
      when: group_user.changed
      # Delegate the call to the worker host(s) -> don't know if it's the expected behavior
      delegate_to: 'worker'
```

### Slave main.yml

```
---
- name: 'Write to a file for deamon setup'
  copy:
    content: "{{ sethostname }}"
    dest: "/tmp/test.text"
```

At the end the `/tmp/test.text` contains the effective user group name.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can i do this for multiple hosts. For eg. here it is working for 'worker' can i do it for 'worker1,worker2' and execute same main.yaml after 'worker' has completed it's task.

Comment: Yes for sure you can run the playbook on multiple hosts (on a group defined in the inventory for example). However what is unclear for me is the where the slave is executed. In my example I've used `delegate_to` but I'm not sure about what you want to achieve (where to gather the inversion vs where to write the result) (see  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation for the usage of delegation).

Comment: I want to keep same slave. When slave execution is completed for worker host i need to execute it for worker1 host.So how i know execution for slave (worker) is completed so that i can execute it for worker1.

Comment: Please respond to my question.

Comment: @DhirajKumar It's not easy for me to answer since I do not know the context. However in ansible the the usual way of working is to run a playbook for an host group say `workers`. If you do not precise anything the playbook will run in //. But you can define different strategies for example by using the `serial: 1` keyword, the playbook will be run for each host in the group one by one. Check [the rolling update doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) for more information. Hope this will help you.